# what is a non static component?

Tags: capacitor

Capacitor are said to be linear but not static.

After reading for a while, through complex explanation, from what I understand is that like a resistance it is linear, but it's linearity may change. If I'm correct, it's linearity would change with the frequency?

Is there anything else than the frequence which can change de linearity or only the frequency?

Comment: I'm guessing you're doing your studies in a different language than English. I have not heard of resistors being referred to as "static". Stuff made up only of resistors is just called "resistive network" from what I've seen.

Comment: aren't the term in english dynamic/static?

Comment: The ideal inductor and the ideal capacitor [unlike a resistor] don't dissipate energy, so I suppose you could call them non-dissipative as a group; I've seldom seen that done, but it's done sometimes: https://books.google.com/books?id=z0IjC_PZbh0C&pg=PA273

Comment: Well, I suppose I should read more books. I did find one that does refer to purely resistive circuits as static [and also as memory-less] and to those with capacitors/inductors as dynamic [or having memory]. https://books.google.com/books?id=KkNkAPc-WcIC&pg=PA422

Comment: Leaving aside that all that, are you asking why a capacitor is considered a linear element?

Comment: Static means the relationship between voltage and current is not a function of time, as displayed by a resistor. Dynamic means that time features in the relationship between v and i, as in a capacitor or inductor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the capacitor. The equation describing a capacitor is

$$I = C\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

We say a system with input \$x(t)\$ and output \$y(t)\$ is linear if the response to an input \$\alpha{}x_1(t)+\beta{}x_2(t)\$ is \$\alpha{}y_1(t)+\beta{}y_2(t)\$. If you know the properties of the derivative operator, you can easily verify that, if the capacitor is initially uncharged, this is true for the capacitor's equation.

> what I understand is that like a resistance it is linear, but it's linearity may change. If I'm correct, it's linearity would change with the frequency?

This is referring to the phasor representation of signals. In the phasor representation, we assume the signals we are interested in are sinusoids with frequency \$\omega\$. Phasor analysis models the *sinusoidal steady state* behavior of a circuit, meaning the response to a sinusoidal stimulus after all initial transient behaviors have decayed until negligible.

In phasor analysis we represent each signal by a complex number that contains information about the magnitude and phase of the sinusoid.

In this representation, the capacitor equation becomes

$$\mathbf{i}=j\omega{}C\mathbf{v}$$

where \$\mathbf{i}\$ and \$\mathbf{v}\$ are the phasors representing the current and voltage signals.

You can see then that \$\mathbf{i}\$ is proportional to \$\mathbf{v}\$ with a proportionality that does depend on the frequency. (We don't say that the "linearity" changes, we say the "constant of proportionality" changes). In this case (a characteristic equation of the form \$\mathbf{i}=Y\mathbf{v}\$) we  call the ratio \$Y\$ the *admittance* of the device.

> Is there anything else than the [frequency] which can change [the] linearity or only the frequency?

You can see that the phasor capacitor equation has terms for both the frequency and the capacitance of the device. So if something changed the capacitance of the device, that would also change the admittance of the capacitor. For example, the capacitance of a *varicap* is changed by changing the dc bias voltage applied to it.

A very similar explanation can be made about the inductor, with some rearrangement of terms and terminology.

Comment: The port-wise linearity of a capacitor holds only if it has no initial charge: https://books.google.com/books?id=k1pBPLnAoEQC&pg=PA5 Also linearity has a double-meaning, because of Q = CV https://books.google.com/books?id=36NDa3mq6bkC&pg=PA44

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, please see my edits.

Comment: If you didn't follow the link, I was referring to your first statement  "We say a system with input \$x(t)\$ and output \$y(t)\$ is linear if the response to an input \$\alpha{}x_1(t)+\beta{}x_2(t)\$ is \$\alpha{}y_1(t)+\beta{}y_2(t)\$. If you know the properties of the derivative operator, you can easily verify that this is true for the capacitor's equation." That is called port-wise linearity. And try to actually prove it to see what's needed in terms of additional assumptions for a capacitor.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, okay, I adjusted that section also.

Comment: (+1) Also, I'm gonna say here that this distinction is basically caused by the difference (and overloaded terminology) between a linear map and an affine map, both being colloquially called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function

Comment: ... which still confuses people http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137628/why-are-linear-functions-linear

Answer (score 1):

An ideal resistor is "static", and "linear" in that its resistance won't change regardless of the frequency or voltage impressed across it, and the current through it will vary only as a linear function of the voltage impressed across it.

An ideal capacitor, on the other hand, will have its reactance change as a function of frequency, linearly, regardless of the voltage impressed across it, so its reactance wouldn't be static, but its capacitance would.

Another very interesting aspect to your question is what happens to a capacitor's capacitance when the voltage across it changes, but that's fuel for another fire...